# How to divide each row of a matrix by elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I would like to divide each **row** of a matrix by a fixed vector. For example

```
mat<-matrix(1,ncol=2,nrow=2,TRUE)
dev<-c(5,10)
```

Giving `mat/dev` divides each **column** by `dev`.

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.2  0.2
[2,]  0.1  0.1
```

However, I would like to have this as a result, i.e. do the operation **row-wise** :

```
rbind(mat[1,]/dev, mat[2,]/dev)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.2  0.1
[2,]  0.2  0.1
```

Is there an explicit command to get there?

Comment: It's important to note that `mat/dev` will only divide each column as you showed if `length(dev) == nrow(mat)`. It's due to the fact that R stores its matrix information in [column major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order).

Comment: It would have been clearer to call the vector `vec` like the matrix is `mat`, but it's too late now.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Here are a few ways in order of increasing code length:

```
t(t(mat) / dev)

mat / dev[col(mat)] #  @DavidArenburg & @akrun

mat %*% diag(1 / dev)

sweep(mat, 2, dev, "/")

t(apply(mat, 1, "/", dev))

plyr::aaply(mat, 1, "/", dev)

mat / rep(dev, each = nrow(mat))

mat / t(replace(t(mat), TRUE, dev))

mapply("/", as.data.frame(mat), dev)  # added later

mat / matrix(dev, nrow(mat), ncol(mat), byrow = TRUE)  # added later

do.call(rbind, lapply(as.data.frame(t(mat)), "/", dev))

mat2 <- mat; for(i in seq_len(nrow(mat2))) mat2[i, ] <- mat2[i, ] / dev
```

### Data Frames

All the solutions that begin with `mat /` also work if `mat` is a data frame and produce a data frame result.  The same is also the case for the `sweep` solution and the last, i.e. `mat2`, solution.  The `mapply` solutions works with data.frames but produces a matrix.

### Vector

If `mat` is a plain vector rather than a matrix then either of these return a one column matrix

```
t(t(mat) / dev)
mat / t(replace(t(mat), TRUE, dev))
```

and this one returns a vector:

```
plyr::aaply(mat, 1, "/", dev)
```

The others give an error, warning or not the desired answer.

### Benchmarks

The brevity and clarity of the code may be more important than speed but for purposes of completeness here are some benchmarks using 10 repetitions and then 100 repetitions.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(plyr)

set.seed(84789)

mat<-matrix(runif(1e6),nrow=1e5)
dev<-runif(10)

microbenchmark(times=10L,
  "1" = t(t(mat) / dev),
  "2" = mat %*% diag(1/dev),
  "3" = sweep(mat, 2, dev, "/"),
  "4" = t(apply(mat, 1, "/", dev)),
  "5" = mat / rep(dev, each = nrow(mat)),
  "6" = mat / t(replace(t(mat), TRUE, dev)),
  "7" = aaply(mat, 1, "/", dev),
  "8" = do.call(rbind, lapply(as.data.frame(t(mat)), "/", dev)),
  "9" = {mat2 <- mat; for(i in seq_len(nrow(mat2))) mat2[i, ] <- mat2[i, ] / dev},
 "10" = mat/dev[col(mat)])
```

giving:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr         min          lq       mean      median          uq        max neval
    1    7.957253    8.136799   44.13317    8.370418    8.597972  366.24246    10
    2    4.678240    4.693771   10.11320    4.708153    4.720309   58.79537    10
    3   15.594488   15.691104   16.38740   15.843637   16.559956   19.98246    10
    4   96.616547  104.743737  124.94650  117.272493  134.852009  177.96882    10
    5   17.631848   17.654821   18.98646   18.295586   20.120382   21.30338    10
    6   19.097557   19.365944   27.78814   20.126037   43.322090   48.76881    10
    7 8279.428898 8496.131747 8631.02530 8644.798642 8741.748155 9194.66980    10
    8  509.528218  524.251103  570.81573  545.627522  568.929481  821.17562    10
    9  161.240680  177.282664  188.30452  186.235811  193.250346  242.45495    10
   10    7.713448    7.815545   11.86550    7.965811    8.807754   45.87518    10
```

Re-running the test on all those that took <20 milliseconds with 100  repetitions:

```
microbenchmark(times=100L,
  "1" = t(t(mat) / dev),
  "2" = mat %*% diag(1/dev),
  "3" = sweep(mat, 2, dev, "/"),
  "5" = mat / rep(dev, each = nrow(mat)),
  "6" = mat / t(replace(t(mat), TRUE, dev)),
 "10" = mat/dev[col(mat)])
```

giving:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    1  8.010749  8.188459 13.972445  8.560578 10.197650 299.80328   100
    2  4.672902  4.734321  5.802965  4.769501  4.985402  20.89999   100
    3 15.224121 15.428518 18.707554 15.836116 17.064866  42.54882   100
    5 17.625347 17.678850 21.464804 17.847698 18.209404 303.27342   100
    6 19.158946 19.361413 22.907115 19.772479 21.142961  38.77585   100
   10  7.754911  7.939305  9.971388  8.010871  8.324860  25.65829   100
```

So on both these tests #2 (using `diag`) is fastest. The reason may lie in its almost direct appeal to the BLAS, whereas #1 relies on the costlier `t`.

Comment: I expect that one of the first two options will be fastest.

Comment: And not the fastest but very explicit: `scale(mat, center = FALSE, scale = dev)`

Comment: This `mat / matrix(dev, 2, 2, T)` seems valid, too.

Comment: @flodel, Note that `scale` uses `sweep` internally.

Comment: @Roland correct; I was hoping `sweep` would be faster, but then I saw all the overhead going on in there

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I just wondered why we never considered simply `t(mat/dev)`? Considering your benchmarking I think this should be even faster.

Comment: @tomka, It gives the right answer for the example in the question but I think the intention was that `mat` can be a general matrix with arbitrary elements and in that case it gives the wrong answer, in general.

Comment: Just one caveat with `mat / dev[col(mat)]`. It doesn't work with "1 column matrix". This problem appears when working with matrix with an arbitrary column number (say, from 2 to 5) and then you want to divide all columns except the first one, i.e. `mat[,-1] <- mat[,-1] / dev[col(mat[,-1])]` give `Error in col(mat[, -1]) : 
  a matrix-like object is required as argument to 'col'`. However `t(t(mat[,-1) / dev)` works fine.

Comment: @Alnair.  Actually it does work with a one column matrix but in your code `mat[, -1]` is not a one-column matrix.  Use `mat[, -1, drop = FALSE]` if you want to catch such edge cases.  See R FAQ 7.5 -- https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-my-matrices-lose-dimensions_003f

Comment: In my hands, using a large, sparse matrix (thousands of columns and rows), `mat %*% diag(1/dev)` is by far the slowest of the first three. 100 seconds compared with less than 1 second.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the `apply` function, applied on the rows:

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x/dev))
```

Comment: Thanks -- ok this seems reaasonably complicated for such a simple operation. Is this the easiest/shortest/briefest way?

Comment: @tomka: is `m.FUN.m..v <- function(FUN) function(m, v) t(FUN(t(m), v)); '%m/v%' <- m.FUN.m..v('/'); M9 <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3); M9 %m/v% 1:3` brief enough? Then you can do `m.FUN.m..v('+')`, etc. almost for free. (Thanks to @g-grothendieck and/or @anton for double-transpose hint (+1); sorry about quotes--how to markup backquotes that are part of code?)

Answer (score 1):

Not only faster than the fastest base method (using matrix multiplication, see [@G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596490/1870254)) but also more readable is the use of [`rray` package](https://github.com/r-lib/rray) that allows numpy-like broadcasting for division with its `%b/%` operator:

`mat %b/% matrix(dev, nrow = 1)`

```r
#install.packages("rray")
library(rray)

set.seed(84789)
mat <- matrix(runif(1e6), nrow = 1e5)
dev <- runif(10)

bench::mark(rray = {ret <- mat %b/% matrix(dev, nrow = 1); attr(ret, "dimnames") <- NULL; ret}, 
            matmult = mat %*% diag(1/dev)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 rray         8.24ms   8.82ms     108.     7.67MB     46.4
#> 2 matmult     11.17ms  12.01ms      77.6    7.66MB     13.9
```