# Dividing rows by terms of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, row, division

This question is very simple. It consists in dividing each row of a matrix by its corresponding number of a vector. For example. I have this matrix:

[3 6

9 12]

And this vector:

5, 10

I want to divide the first row of the matrix by the first number of the vector, and the second row of the matrix by the second number of the vector. So that the result would be:

[0.6 1.2

0.9 1.2]

I have tried matrix/vector (option A) and matrix/rep(vector,each=nrow(matrix)) (option B), following [How to divide each row of a matrix by elements of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596433/how-to-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-elements-of-a-vector-in-r). However, as you can see below the results aren't the same.

A)

[0.6  1.8

0.6  1.2]

B)

[0.6  0.9

1.2  1.2]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you really want to divide each column by the vector?

Comment: Hi Matthew. I'll try to explain myself better. I am not looking for option A or option B. Those are the ones that I have found in Stackoverflow Forums and the result isn't the same. I am looking for the answer matrix I wrote above. I need to divide the first column of the matrix by the first term of the vector, the second row of the matrix by the second term and so on. In the example I posted above, the answer should be: 3/5 and 6/5 for the first row. And 9/10 , 12/10 for the second one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to divide each column by the vector.

```
a <- matrix(c(3,9,6,12), 2)
dev <- c(5,10)

a/dev
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.6  1.2
[2,]  0.9  1.2
```

Here, the vector `dev` is extended to the length of `a` by recycling.  Since `a` stores the data column-wise, the division returns the result of dividing each column by `dev`.

Comment: Your answer seems to work perfectly Mark. I don't know what had happened to my R output. Do you knoy if I can use your answer if "a" comes from a list and "dev" is a vector? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user3183321 This answer depends on `a` being a matrix.  How you would do this for a list depends on the structure of that list.