# R: Repeat script n times, changing variables in each iteration

Tags: r, loops, iteration, repeat

I have a script that I want to repeat n times, where some variables are changed by 1 each iteration. I'm creating a data frame consisting of the standard deviation of the difference of various vectors. My script currently looks like this:

```
standard.deviation <- data.frame
c(
 sd(diff(t1[,1])),
 sd(diff(t1[,2])),
 sd(diff(t1[,3])),
 sd(diff(t1[,4])),
 sd(diff(t1[,5]))
 ),
c(
  sd(diff(t2[,1])),
  sd(diff(t2[,2])),
  sd(diff(t2[,3])),
  sd(diff(t2[,4])),
  sd(diff(t2[,5]))
 ), 
c(
  sd(diff(t3[,1])),
  sd(diff(t3[,2])),
  sd(diff(t3[,3])),
  sd(diff(t3[,4])),
  sd(diff(t3[,5]))
 ),
)
```

I want to write the script creating the vector only once, and repeat it n times (n=3 in this example) so that I end up with n vectors. In each iteration, I want to add 1 to a variable (in this case: 1 -> 2 -> 3, so the number next to 't'). t1, t2 and t3 are all separate data frames, and I can't figure out how to loop a script with changing data frame names.

1) How to make this happen?

2) I would also like to divide each sd value in a row by the row number. How would I do this?

3) I will be using 140 data frames in total. Is there a way to call all of these with a simple function, rather than making a list and adding each of the 140 data frames individually?

Comment: As already stated, how do you get your 140 data frames in R environment at first ? It's probably at this point that the list could be built.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. Note that once you post a question or answer to this site, those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you always want to use columns 1 to 5...

```
# some data 
t3 <- t2 <- t1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10))

# script itself
lis=list(t1,t2,t3)
sapply(lis,function(x) sapply(x[,1:5],function(y) sd(diff(y))))

#        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# V1 1.733599 1.733599 1.733599
# V2 1.577737 1.577737 1.577737
# V3 1.574130 1.574130 1.574130
# V4 1.158639 1.158639 1.158639
# V5 0.999489 0.999489 0.999489
```

The output is a matrix, so `as.data.frame` should fix that.

For completeness: As @Tensibai mentions, you can just use `list(mget(ls(pattern="^t[0-9]+$")))`, assuming that all your variables are `t` followed by a number.

Edit: Thanks to @Tensibai for pointing out a missing step and improving the code, and the `mget` step.

Comment: You can use a list as input and avoid calling get in sapply (BTW I think OP wants the sd of the diff of each columns, unsure you're getting the correct values here)

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks, added `diff`. Regarding `get`, my reasoning was that I didn't want to create a very large object, so I figured that `get` would be a nice solution given the context (i.e. existing data frames).

Comment: Unless I'm absolutely mistaken, list store only references, so putting a data.frame into a list does not build a large object, just a 3 entries object.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I checked it with `tracemem`. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped me a lot. The only thing I haven't mentioned yet (sorry about that), is that I want to divide each value within a row by the row number: So the value in 2nd row should be divided by 2 and so on. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: Also, I will be working with 140 data frames in the end. Would I have to include 140 variables in list(), or is there a more efficient way to do this? So what I mean is: list(t1 *until* t140).
Thank you all for your help. I'm new to all of this, so I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Joseph edit your question is there's something else, but here you're changing into a help vampire, changing the question when you got an answer. State your full problem once.

Comment: @Joseph and I'm pretty sure the way you get these 140 data.frame at first can be changed to put them into a list at first...

Comment: I'm very sorry about that Tensibai, I'll change the question.

Comment: For dividing, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596433/how-to-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-elements-of-a-vector-in-r). Or Google around a bit more.

Comment: I've managed to divide by the number of rows by adding a line: y<-y/seq_len(nrow(y)). However, I can't find a way to include this command in the original line (starting with sapply()). Do you have any suggestions? Also, I haven't been able to figure out how to make a sequence in the list. I have tried list(paste("t",c(1,2,3),sep="")), but unfortunately then the values are simply turned into a single string and I can't use them as variables. Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks again.

Comment: @Joseph see the answer history, version which use a list of strings and use get(x) later in

Comment: @Joseph or use `mget` like this `mget(ls(pattern = "^t\\d+$"))` (assuming your data frames are names t1 to t140)

Comment: @Joseph consider accepting and answer to let other know the problem is solved (click on the tick mark next the best answer for you)

Answer (score 4):

Use functions to get a more readable code:

```
set.seed(123) # so you'll get the same number as this example
t1 <- t2 <- t3 <- data.frame(replicate(5,runif(10)))

# make a function for your sd of diff
sd.cols <- function(data) {
  # loop over the df columns
  sapply(data,function(x) sd(diff(x)))
}

# make a list of your data frames
dflist <- list(sdt1=t1,sdt2=t2,sdt3=t3)
# Loop overthe list
result <- data.frame(lapply(dflist,sd.cols))
```

Which gives:

```
> result
       sdt1      sdt2      sdt3
1 0.4887692 0.4887692 0.4887692
2 0.5140287 0.5140287 0.5140287
3 0.2137486 0.2137486 0.2137486
4 0.3856857 0.3856857 0.3856857
5 0.2548264 0.2548264 0.2548264
```

Answer (score 1):

You can itterate through a list of the ts...

```
ans <- data.frame()
dats <- c(t, t1 , t2)
for (k in  dats){
     temp <- c()
     for (k2 in c(1,2,3,4,5)){
          temp <- c(temp , sd(k[,k2]))
     }
ans <- rbind(ans,temp)
}

rownames(ans) <- c("t1","t2","t3")
colnames(ans) <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
attr(results,"title") <- "standard deviation"
```