# Sliding normalising window in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sliding-window

I have a dataframe which has 7 variables which I would like to apply a rolling normalising window to. My dataframe has no NA values and all variables are of the same length.

```
> head(CK0159U09A3,10)
            W1          W2         W3        W4         W5         W6         W7
1   1.37853716  0.01316304 -0.1363012 0.6895341 -0.7230930 -0.1310321 -0.4109521
2  -0.73032998  0.31212925  0.1654731 0.9187255 -0.8017260 -0.1619631 -0.4243575
3  -0.52130420  0.43831484  0.6088623 1.1183964 -0.8486971 -0.1970389 -0.4368820
4   0.55501096  0.13850401  1.1221211 1.2708212 -0.8701385 -0.2372061 -0.4490060
5  -0.06995122 -0.53842548  1.4592013 1.3581935 -0.8661200 -0.2791726 -0.4608654
6  -0.19984548 -0.78829431  1.4564180 1.3823090 -0.8431200 -0.3184653 -0.4722506
7   0.68935525  0.18733222  1.0158497 1.3344059 -0.8043461 -0.3526886 -0.4825229
8  -0.49540738  0.80663376  0.1774945 1.1800970 -0.7494087 -0.3803636 -0.4901212
9  -0.09501622 -0.17931684 -0.7074083 0.9312984 -0.6801124 -0.4008524 -0.4942994
10 -0.14939548 -0.68153738 -1.2723772 0.6054420 -0.5968207 -0.4149125 -0.4952316
```

My window is defined as size 3

```
windowSize <- 3
```

I would like to apply a rolling window of size = 3 to each variable within my dataframe. The normalising function uses the following logic:

1. calculates the standard deviation of the entire variable (length(CK0159U09A3[,1].....)
2. then applies the window of size = 3 to the first 3 values and calculates their averages
3. For the first value in the window it subtracts the average of the three values and then divides by the standard deviation
4. The function then increments by 1 and performs the same steps on the next three values for all 7 columns.

I know about the rollapply/r functions in zoo but I can't fathom how to write the section about taking the current value and performing the subtraction and division and then incrementing to the next value. If you can't tell already, I am not a strong programmer.

I believe it's already been captured in the first answer below but when the sliding window reaches the end of the column and there are less values than the window size then NAs should be returned.

Any help in cracking this would be greatly appreciated.

Just for clarity here is the logic I am trying to implement with math

```
1.3785 - ((1.378+(-0.7303)+(-0.5213)/windowSize))/S.D of column

-0.7303 - ((-0.7303+(-0.5213)+0.555)/windowSize))/S.D of column

-0.5213 - ((-0.5213+0.555+(-0.0699))/windowSize))/S.D of column
```

Comment: What happens for the bottom two rows, where there are not 2 trailing values? It would help if you give the *expected output*; perhaps calculate it by hand for the top few rows so that we have something to verify against.

Comment: @r2evans, you're spot on, I never stated what should happen once there are less values than the size of the window. I have updated the original post stating that NAs should be returned. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** If `DF` is the input data.frame, calculate the rolling means, subtract those from the original data frame and then divide each column by the corresponding sd value.  If you don't want the NA rows then use `na.omit(out)`.

Note that the answer to this question is relevant here: [How to divide each row of a matrix by elements of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596433/how-to-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-elements-of-a-vector-in-r/20596490#20596490)

```
library(zoo)

out <- t( t(DF - rollmean(DF, 3, fill = NA, align = "left")) / sapply(DF, sd))
```

giving:

```
> out
           W1          W2         W3           W4         W5        W6        W7
1   2.0571604 -0.46799047 -0.3798546 -0.782516058  0.7559711 0.3162800 0.4320913
2  -0.7668684  0.03065979 -0.5079677 -0.656126126  0.4270853 0.3599383 0.4083388
3  -0.7839578  0.82502267 -0.4947466 -0.466405606  0.1438538 0.3990324 0.3966334
4   0.7080855  1.03647378 -0.2435920 -0.236471919 -0.1148815 0.4020498 0.3856112
5  -0.3229973 -0.30756238  0.1618686 -0.000389918 -0.3137854 0.3680621 0.3629682
6  -0.3046393 -1.66132459  0.6238737  0.297421141 -0.4903858 0.3136170 0.3091448
7   1.0105062 -0.16328686  0.9294159  0.662844512 -0.6631908 0.2474401 0.2128288
8  -0.3830338  1.59900097  0.8471133  0.979199212 -0.8212911 0.1795721 0.1020336
9          NA          NA         NA           NA         NA        NA        NA
10         NA          NA         NA           NA         NA        NA        NA
```

Correcting the formulas in the question the first 3 values in column 1 are:

```
(1.3785 - (1.378+(-0.7303)+(-0.5213))/3)/sd(DF[, 1])
## [1] 2.057361
(-0.7303 - (-0.7303+(-0.5213)+0.555)/3)/sd(DF[, 1])
## -0.7668342
(-0.5213 - (-0.5213+0.555+(-0.0699))/3)/sd(DF[, 1])
## [1] -0.7839742
```

**2)** An alternate solution would be to define a function which performs the required operation on a single column then `sapply` it to each column.

```
sapply(DF, function(x) (x - rollmean(x, 3, align = "left", fill = NA))/sd(x))
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <-  " W1          W2         W3        W4         W5         W6         W7
1   1.37853716  0.01316304 -0.1363012 0.6895341 -0.7230930 -0.1310321 -0.4109521
2  -0.73032998  0.31212925  0.1654731 0.9187255 -0.8017260 -0.1619631 -0.4243575
3  -0.52130420  0.43831484  0.6088623 1.1183964 -0.8486971 -0.1970389 -0.4368820
4   0.55501096  0.13850401  1.1221211 1.2708212 -0.8701385 -0.2372061 -0.4490060
5  -0.06995122 -0.53842548  1.4592013 1.3581935 -0.8661200 -0.2791726 -0.4608654
6  -0.19984548 -0.78829431  1.4564180 1.3823090 -0.8431200 -0.3184653 -0.4722506
7   0.68935525  0.18733222  1.0158497 1.3344059 -0.8043461 -0.3526886 -0.4825229
8  -0.49540738  0.80663376  0.1774945 1.1800970 -0.7494087 -0.3803636 -0.4901212
9  -0.09501622 -0.17931684 -0.7074083 0.9312984 -0.6801124 -0.4008524 -0.4942994
10 -0.14939548 -0.68153738 -1.2723772 0.6054420 -0.5968207 -0.4149125 -0.4952316"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick reply that was a huge help.