# R Divide a Dataframe by a Vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe table like so named `cohort_table`:

```
   CohortPeriod 2009-01 2009-02 2009-03 2009-04 2009-05 2009-06 2009-07 2009-08 2009-09 2009-10 2009-11 2009-12 2010-01 2010-02
1             1      22      15      13      39      50      32      50      31      37      54     130      65      95     100
2             2       8       3       4      13      13      15      23      11      15      17      32      17      50      19
3             3      10       5       5      10      12       9      13       9      14      12      26      18      26      NA
4             4       9       1       4      13       5       6      10       7       8      13      29       7      NA      NA
5             5      10       4       1       6       4       7      11       6      13      13      13      NA      NA      NA
6             6       8       4       2       7       6       5      10       8       9       7      NA      NA      NA      NA
7             7       8       4       2       4       3       3      11       4       8      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8             8       7       5       3       6       5       3       7       4      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9             9       7       5       2       2       5      10       7      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10           10       7       4       1       4       4       3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
11           11       7       3       3       3       3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
12           12       8       3       2       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
13           13      11       5       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
14           14       7      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
15           15       6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
   2010-03
1       24
2       NA
3       NA
4       NA
5       NA
6       NA
7       NA
8       NA
9       NA
10      NA
11      NA
12      NA
13      NA
14      NA
15      NA
```

I have another dataframe like so named `cohort_group_size`:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Groups:   CohortGroup [15]
   CohortGroup InitialGroupSize
   <chr>                  <int>
 1 2009-01                   22
 2 2009-02                   15
 3 2009-03                   13
 4 2009-04                   39
 5 2009-05                   50
 6 2009-06                   32
 7 2009-07                   50
 8 2009-08                   31
 9 2009-09                   37
10 2009-10                   54
11 2009-11                  130
12 2009-12                   65
13 2010-01                   95
14 2010-02                  100
15 2010-03                   24
```

Basically, I'm trying to divide the `cohort_table` by `cohort_group_size`. Notice that the `cohort_group_size` CohortGroup column has the same labels as the headers of the `cohort_table`.

For example, 2009-01 has an InitialGroupSize of 22. I want to take that 22 and divide the entire column 2009-01 in `cohort_table` by 22. And so-on, so-forth for each column.

In Python Pandas, concepts of indexes exist so I can do the following when `cohort_group_size` is a Pandas Series:

```
cohort_table / cohort_group_size

CohortGroup    2009-01   2009-02   2009-03   2009-04  2009-05  2009-06  \
CohortPeriod                                                             
1             1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000     1.00  1.00000   
2             0.363636  0.200000  0.307692  0.333333     0.26  0.46875   
3             0.454545  0.333333  0.384615  0.256410     0.24  0.28125   
4             0.409091  0.066667  0.307692  0.333333     0.10  0.18750   
5             0.454545  0.266667  0.076923  0.153846     0.08  0.21875   
6             0.363636  0.266667  0.153846  0.179487     0.12  0.15625   
7             0.363636  0.266667  0.153846  0.102564     0.06  0.09375   
8             0.318182  0.333333  0.230769  0.153846     0.10  0.09375   
9             0.318182  0.333333  0.153846  0.051282     0.10  0.31250   
10            0.318182  0.266667  0.076923  0.102564     0.08  0.09375   
11            0.318182  0.200000  0.230769  0.076923     0.06      NaN   
12            0.363636  0.200000  0.153846  0.051282      NaN      NaN   
13            0.500000  0.333333  0.076923       NaN      NaN      NaN   
14            0.318182       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   
15            0.272727       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN   

CohortGroup   2009-07   2009-08   2009-09   2009-10   2009-11   2009-12  \
CohortPeriod                                                              
1                1.00  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   
2                0.46  0.354839  0.405405  0.314815  0.246154  0.261538   
3                0.26  0.290323  0.378378  0.222222  0.200000  0.276923   
4                0.20  0.225806  0.216216  0.240741  0.223077  0.107692   
5                0.22  0.193548  0.351351  0.240741  0.100000       NaN   
6                0.20  0.258065  0.243243  0.129630       NaN       NaN   
7                0.22  0.129032  0.216216       NaN       NaN       NaN   
8                0.14  0.129032       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
9                0.14       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
10                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
11                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
12                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
13                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
14                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
15                NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

CohortGroup    2010-01  2010-02  2010-03  
CohortPeriod                              
1             1.000000     1.00      1.0  
2             0.526316     0.19      NaN  
3             0.273684      NaN      NaN  
4                  NaN      NaN      NaN  
5                  NaN      NaN      NaN  
6                  NaN      NaN      NaN  
7                  NaN      NaN      NaN  
8                  NaN      NaN      NaN  
9                  NaN      NaN      NaN  
10                 NaN      NaN      NaN  
11                 NaN      NaN      NaN  
12                 NaN      NaN      NaN  
13                 NaN      NaN      NaN  
14                 NaN      NaN      NaN  
15                 NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Table immediately above is the desired output. Coming from Python, without the use of Indices, I'm unsure how to apply division from a series / vector to a dataframe especially in this case since the column names are across the headers and this dataframe contains a column to exclude from the division `CohortPeriod`.

Comment: How do you create ```cohort_group_size``` ? Maybe you can do in one step creation of ```cohort_group_size``` and divide. 
A more complex way should be : ```cohort_table %>% reshape::melt(id.vars="CohortPeriod") %>% dplyr::left_join(cohort_group_size, by = c("variable"="CohortGroup") %>% dplyr::mutate(value = value/InitialGroupSize)```
The concept is to merge the two tables and apply a divide operation. You can do ```reshape2::dcast``` to return to ```wide``` format. 
If this solution seems good to you I can do a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a fairly similar approach that works in `R`:

```r
# Create a dataframe from the example provided
cohort_table <- read.table(text = "   CohortPeriod 2009-01 2009-02 2009-03 2009-04 2009-05 2009-06 2009-07 2009-08 2009-09 2009-10 2009-11 2009-12 2010-01 2010-02 2010-03
1             1      22      15      13      39      50      32      50      31      37      54     130      65      95     100     24
2             2       8       3       4      13      13      15      23      11      15      17      32      17      50      19     NA
3             3      10       5       5      10      12       9      13       9      14      12      26      18      26      NA     NA
4             4       9       1       4      13       5       6      10       7       8      13      29       7      NA      NA     NA
5             5      10       4       1       6       4       7      11       6      13      13      13      NA      NA      NA     NA
6             6       8       4       2       7       6       5      10       8       9       7      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
7             7       8       4       2       4       3       3      11       4       8      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
8             8       7       5       3       6       5       3       7       4      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
9             9       7       5       2       2       5      10       7      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
10           10       7       4       1       4       4       3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
11           11       7       3       3       3       3      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
12           12       8       3       2       2      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
13           13      11       5       1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
14           14       7      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA
15           15       6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     NA")

# Setup column names to match the example. Note that R dislikes '-' in names
# and that names should not start with a number. You can, however, force it
# for the sake of making them match.
colnames(cohort_table) <- gsub("X", "", colnames(cohort_table))
colnames(cohort_table) <- gsub("[.]", "-", colnames(cohort_table))
rownames(cohort_table) <- cohort_table$CohortPeriod

# Create a dataframe from the example provided
cohort_group <- read.table(text = "   CohortGroup InitialGroupSize
 1 2009-01                   22
 2 2009-02                   15
 3 2009-03                   13
 4 2009-04                   39
 5 2009-05                   50
 6 2009-06                   32
 7 2009-07                   50
 8 2009-08                   31
 9 2009-09                   37
10 2009-10                   54
11 2009-11                  130
12 2009-12                   65
13 2010-01                   95
14 2010-02                  100
15 2010-03                   24")

# IMPORTANT: set up the rownames of the cohort_group to match the month
# This means that you can index the df based on the month, matching the
# rownames: e.g. cohort_group["2009-01",]
rownames(cohort_group) <- cohort_group$CohortGroup

# R will divide vectors rowwise, so transpose the cohort_table
# divide by the vector of values (cohort_group$InitialGroupSize)
# then transpose back into a table. Note that this requires the 
# columns in cohort_table to be in the same order as the rows of
# cohort_group.
t(t(cohort_table) / cohort_group$InitialGroupSize)
#>    CohortPeriod    2009-01    2009-02    2009-03    2009-04    2009-05
#> 1    0.04545455 1.46666667 1.15384615 0.33333333 0.78000000 1.56250000
#> 2    0.13333333 0.61538462 0.07692308 0.08000000 0.40625000 0.26000000
#> 3    0.23076923 0.25641026 0.10000000 0.15625000 0.20000000 0.38709677
#> 4    0.10256410 0.18000000 0.03125000 0.08000000 0.41935484 0.13513514
#> 5    0.10000000 0.31250000 0.08000000 0.03225806 0.16216216 0.07407407
#> 6    0.18750000 0.16000000 0.12903226 0.05405405 0.12962963 0.04615385
#> 7    0.14000000 0.25806452 0.10810811 0.03703704 0.03076923 0.04615385
#> 8    0.25806452 0.18918919 0.09259259 0.02307692 0.09230769 0.05263158
#> 9    0.24324324 0.12962963 0.03846154 0.03076923 0.02105263 0.05000000
#> 10   0.18518519 0.05384615 0.06153846 0.01052632 0.04000000 0.16666667
#> 11   0.08461538 0.10769231 0.03157895 0.03000000 0.12500000 0.13636364
#> 12   0.18461538 0.08421053 0.03000000 0.08333333 0.09090909         NA
#> 13   0.13684211 0.11000000 0.20833333 0.04545455         NA         NA
#> 14   0.14000000 0.29166667         NA         NA         NA         NA
#> 15   0.62500000 0.27272727         NA         NA         NA         NA
#>       2009-06    2009-07    2009-08    2009-09   2009-10   2009-11
#> 1  0.64000000 1.61290323 0.83783784 0.68518519 0.4153846 2.0000000
#> 2  0.48387097 0.62162162 0.20370370 0.11538462 0.2615385 0.3368421
#> 3  0.24324324 0.24074074 0.06923077 0.21538462 0.1263158 0.2600000
#> 4  0.11111111 0.07692308 0.10769231 0.08421053 0.1300000 1.2083333
#> 5  0.05384615 0.16923077 0.06315789 0.13000000 0.5416667 0.5909091
#> 6  0.07692308 0.10526316 0.08000000 0.37500000 0.3181818        NA
#> 7  0.03157895 0.11000000 0.16666667 0.36363636        NA        NA
#> 8  0.03000000 0.29166667 0.18181818         NA        NA        NA
#> 9  0.41666667 0.31818182         NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 10 0.13636364         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 11         NA         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 12         NA         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 13         NA         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 14         NA         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
#> 15         NA         NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
#>      2009-12  2010-01   2010-02  2010-03
#> 1  0.6842105 0.950000 4.1666667 1.090909
#> 2  0.1700000 2.083333 0.8636364       NA
#> 3  0.7500000 1.181818        NA       NA
#> 4  0.3181818       NA        NA       NA
#> 5         NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 6         NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 7         NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 8         NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 9         NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 10        NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 11        NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 12        NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 13        NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 14        NA       NA        NA       NA
#> 15        NA       NA        NA       NA

# If you aren't sure that the columns and rows will match exactly
# then you can reorder cohort_group by indexing it on the column names
# of cohort_table. Any column that doesn't have a correspoing row in
# cohort group will be divided by NA and so be all NA.
t(t(cohort_table) / cohort_group[colnames(cohort_table), "InitialGroupSize"])
#>    CohortPeriod   2009-01    2009-02    2009-03    2009-04 2009-05 2009-06
#> 1            NA 1.0000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000    1.00 1.00000
#> 2            NA 0.3636364 0.20000000 0.30769231 0.33333333    0.26 0.46875
#> 3            NA 0.4545455 0.33333333 0.38461538 0.25641026    0.24 0.28125
#> 4            NA 0.4090909 0.06666667 0.30769231 0.33333333    0.10 0.18750
#> 5            NA 0.4545455 0.26666667 0.07692308 0.15384615    0.08 0.21875
#> 6            NA 0.3636364 0.26666667 0.15384615 0.17948718    0.12 0.15625
#> 7            NA 0.3636364 0.26666667 0.15384615 0.10256410    0.06 0.09375
#> 8            NA 0.3181818 0.33333333 0.23076923 0.15384615    0.10 0.09375
#> 9            NA 0.3181818 0.33333333 0.15384615 0.05128205    0.10 0.31250
#> 10           NA 0.3181818 0.26666667 0.07692308 0.10256410    0.08 0.09375
#> 11           NA 0.3181818 0.20000000 0.23076923 0.07692308    0.06      NA
#> 12           NA 0.3636364 0.20000000 0.15384615 0.05128205      NA      NA
#> 13           NA 0.5000000 0.33333333 0.07692308         NA      NA      NA
#> 14           NA 0.3181818         NA         NA         NA      NA      NA
#> 15           NA 0.2727273         NA         NA         NA      NA      NA
#>    2009-07   2009-08   2009-09   2009-10   2009-11   2009-12   2010-01
#> 1     1.00 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
#> 2     0.46 0.3548387 0.4054054 0.3148148 0.2461538 0.2615385 0.5263158
#> 3     0.26 0.2903226 0.3783784 0.2222222 0.2000000 0.2769231 0.2736842
#> 4     0.20 0.2258065 0.2162162 0.2407407 0.2230769 0.1076923        NA
#> 5     0.22 0.1935484 0.3513514 0.2407407 0.1000000        NA        NA
#> 6     0.20 0.2580645 0.2432432 0.1296296        NA        NA        NA
#> 7     0.22 0.1290323 0.2162162        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 8     0.14 0.1290323        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 9     0.14        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 10      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 11      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 12      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 13      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 14      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 15      NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
#>    2010-02 2010-03
#> 1     1.00       1
#> 2     0.19      NA
#> 3       NA      NA
#> 4       NA      NA
#> 5       NA      NA
#> 6       NA      NA
#> 7       NA      NA
#> 8       NA      NA
#> 9       NA      NA
#> 10      NA      NA
#> 11      NA      NA
#> 12      NA      NA
#> 13      NA      NA
#> 14      NA      NA
#> 15      NA      NA
```

That said, it's not a very '`R`' way of doing things. A better approach would be to have your data in a tidy format (one row per variable). Thus your `cohort_table` would have columns: `CohortPeriod`, `CohortGroup`, `value`. Then you could merge the `cohort_table` and `cohort_group` dataframes based on `CohortGroup` and perform the division.

```r
(cohort_table <- tidyr::gather(cohort_table, CohortGroup, value, -CohortPeriod))
#>     CohortPeriod CohortGroup value
#> 1              1     2009-01    22
#> 2              2     2009-01     8
#> 3              3     2009-01    10
#> 4              4     2009-01     9
#> 5              5     2009-01    10
#> 6              6     2009-01     8
#> 7              7     2009-01     8
#> 8              8     2009-01     7
#> 9              9     2009-01     7
#> 10            10     2009-01     7
#> 11            11     2009-01     7
#> 12            12     2009-01     8
#> 13            13     2009-01    11
#> 14            14     2009-01     7
#> 15            15     2009-01     6
#> 16             1     2009-02    15
#> 17             2     2009-02     3
#> 18             3     2009-02     5
#> 19             4     2009-02     1
#> 20             5     2009-02     4
#> 21             6     2009-02     4
#> 22             7     2009-02     4
#> 23             8     2009-02     5
#> 24             9     2009-02     5
#> 25            10     2009-02     4
#> 26            11     2009-02     3
#> 27            12     2009-02     3
#> 28            13     2009-02     5
#> 29            14     2009-02    NA
#> 30            15     2009-02    NA
#> 31             1     2009-03    13
#> 32             2     2009-03     4
#> 33             3     2009-03     5
#> 34             4     2009-03     4
#> 35             5     2009-03     1
#> 36             6     2009-03     2
#> 37             7     2009-03     2
#> 38             8     2009-03     3
#> 39             9     2009-03     2
#> 40            10     2009-03     1
#> 41            11     2009-03     3
#> 42            12     2009-03     2
#> 43            13     2009-03     1
#> 44            14     2009-03    NA
#> 45            15     2009-03    NA
#> 46             1     2009-04    39
#> 47             2     2009-04    13
#> 48             3     2009-04    10
#> 49             4     2009-04    13
#> 50             5     2009-04     6
#> 51             6     2009-04     7
#> 52             7     2009-04     4
#> 53             8     2009-04     6
#> 54             9     2009-04     2
#> 55            10     2009-04     4
#> 56            11     2009-04     3
#> 57            12     2009-04     2
#> 58            13     2009-04    NA
#> 59            14     2009-04    NA
#> 60            15     2009-04    NA
#> 61             1     2009-05    50
#> 62             2     2009-05    13
#> 63             3     2009-05    12
#> 64             4     2009-05     5
#> 65             5     2009-05     4
#> 66             6     2009-05     6
#> 67             7     2009-05     3
#> 68             8     2009-05     5
#> 69             9     2009-05     5
#> 70            10     2009-05     4
#> 71            11     2009-05     3
#> 72            12     2009-05    NA
#> 73            13     2009-05    NA
#> 74            14     2009-05    NA
#> 75            15     2009-05    NA
#> 76             1     2009-06    32
#> 77             2     2009-06    15
#> 78             3     2009-06     9
#> 79             4     2009-06     6
#> 80             5     2009-06     7
#> 81             6     2009-06     5
#> 82             7     2009-06     3
#> 83             8     2009-06     3
#> 84             9     2009-06    10
#> 85            10     2009-06     3
#> 86            11     2009-06    NA
#> 87            12     2009-06    NA
#> 88            13     2009-06    NA
#> 89            14     2009-06    NA
#> 90            15     2009-06    NA
#> 91             1     2009-07    50
#> 92             2     2009-07    23
#> 93             3     2009-07    13
#> 94             4     2009-07    10
#> 95             5     2009-07    11
#> 96             6     2009-07    10
#> 97             7     2009-07    11
#> 98             8     2009-07     7
#> 99             9     2009-07     7
#> 100           10     2009-07    NA

(cohort_join <- dplyr::inner_join(cohort_table, cohort_group))
#> Joining, by = "CohortGroup"
#> Warning: Column `CohortGroup` joining character vector and factor, coercing
#> into character vector
#>     CohortPeriod CohortGroup value InitialGroupSize
#> 1              1     2009-01    22               22
#> 2              2     2009-01     8               22
#> 3              3     2009-01    10               22
#> 4              4     2009-01     9               22
#> 5              5     2009-01    10               22
#> 6              6     2009-01     8               22
#> 7              7     2009-01     8               22
#> 8              8     2009-01     7               22
#> 9              9     2009-01     7               22
#> 10            10     2009-01     7               22
#> 11            11     2009-01     7               22
#> 12            12     2009-01     8               22
#> 13            13     2009-01    11               22
#> 14            14     2009-01     7               22
#> 15            15     2009-01     6               22
#> 16             1     2009-02    15               15
#> 17             2     2009-02     3               15
#> 18             3     2009-02     5               15
#> 19             4     2009-02     1               15
#> 20             5     2009-02     4               15
#> 21             6     2009-02     4               15
#> 22             7     2009-02     4               15
#> 23             8     2009-02     5               15
#> 24             9     2009-02     5               15
#> 25            10     2009-02     4               15
#> 26            11     2009-02     3               15
#> 27            12     2009-02     3               15
#> 28            13     2009-02     5               15
#> 29            14     2009-02    NA               15
#> 30            15     2009-02    NA               15
#> 31             1     2009-03    13               13
#> 32             2     2009-03     4               13
#> 33             3     2009-03     5               13
#> 34             4     2009-03     4               13
#> 35             5     2009-03     1               13
#> 36             6     2009-03     2               13
#> 37             7     2009-03     2               13
#> 38             8     2009-03     3               13
#> 39             9     2009-03     2               13
#> 40            10     2009-03     1               13
#> 41            11     2009-03     3               13
#> 42            12     2009-03     2               13
#> 43            13     2009-03     1               13
#> 44            14     2009-03    NA               13
#> 45            15     2009-03    NA               13
#> 46             1     2009-04    39               39
#> 47             2     2009-04    13               39
#> 48             3     2009-04    10               39
#> 49             4     2009-04    13               39
#> 50             5     2009-04     6               39
#> 51             6     2009-04     7               39
#> 52             7     2009-04     4               39
#> 53             8     2009-04     6               39
#> 54             9     2009-04     2               39
#> 55            10     2009-04     4               39
#> 56            11     2009-04     3               39
#> 57            12     2009-04     2               39
#> 58            13     2009-04    NA               39
#> 59            14     2009-04    NA               39
#> 60            15     2009-04    NA               39
#> 61             1     2009-05    50               50
#> 62             2     2009-05    13               50
#> 63             3     2009-05    12               50
#> 64             4     2009-05     5               50
#> 65             5     2009-05     4               50
#> 66             6     2009-05     6               50
#> 67             7     2009-05     3               50
#> 68             8     2009-05     5               50
#> 69             9     2009-05     5               50
#> 70            10     2009-05     4               50
#> 71            11     2009-05     3               50
#> 72            12     2009-05    NA               50
#> 73            13     2009-05    NA               50
#> 74            14     2009-05    NA               50
#> 75            15     2009-05    NA               50
#> 76             1     2009-06    32               32
#> 77             2     2009-06    15               32
#> 78             3     2009-06     9               32
#> 79             4     2009-06     6               32
#> 80             5     2009-06     7               32
#> 81             6     2009-06     5               32
#> 82             7     2009-06     3               32
#> 83             8     2009-06     3               32
#> 84             9     2009-06    10               32
#> 85            10     2009-06     3               32
#> 86            11     2009-06    NA               32
#> 87            12     2009-06    NA               32
#> 88            13     2009-06    NA               32
#> 89            14     2009-06    NA               32
#> 90            15     2009-06    NA               32
#> 91             1     2009-07    50               50
#> 92             2     2009-07    23               50
#> 93             3     2009-07    13               50
#> 94             4     2009-07    10               50
#> 95             5     2009-07    11               50
#> 96             6     2009-07    10               50
#> 97             7     2009-07    11               50
#> 98             8     2009-07     7               50
#> 99             9     2009-07     7               50
#> 100           10     2009-07    NA               50

(dplyr::mutate(cohort_join, divided_value = value/InitialGroupSize))
#>     CohortPeriod CohortGroup value InitialGroupSize divided_value
#> 1              1     2009-01    22               22    1.00000000
#> 2              2     2009-01     8               22    0.36363636
#> 3              3     2009-01    10               22    0.45454545
#> 4              4     2009-01     9               22    0.40909091
#> 5              5     2009-01    10               22    0.45454545
#> 6              6     2009-01     8               22    0.36363636
#> 7              7     2009-01     8               22    0.36363636
#> 8              8     2009-01     7               22    0.31818182
#> 9              9     2009-01     7               22    0.31818182
#> 10            10     2009-01     7               22    0.31818182
#> 11            11     2009-01     7               22    0.31818182
#> 12            12     2009-01     8               22    0.36363636
#> 13            13     2009-01    11               22    0.50000000
#> 14            14     2009-01     7               22    0.31818182
#> 15            15     2009-01     6               22    0.27272727
#> 16             1     2009-02    15               15    1.00000000
#> 17             2     2009-02     3               15    0.20000000
#> 18             3     2009-02     5               15    0.33333333
#> 19             4     2009-02     1               15    0.06666667
#> 20             5     2009-02     4               15    0.26666667
#> 21             6     2009-02     4               15    0.26666667
#> 22             7     2009-02     4               15    0.26666667
#> 23             8     2009-02     5               15    0.33333333
#> 24             9     2009-02     5               15    0.33333333
#> 25            10     2009-02     4               15    0.26666667
#> 26            11     2009-02     3               15    0.20000000
#> 27            12     2009-02     3               15    0.20000000
#> 28            13     2009-02     5               15    0.33333333
#> 29            14     2009-02    NA               15            NA
#> 30            15     2009-02    NA               15            NA
#> 31             1     2009-03    13               13    1.00000000
#> 32             2     2009-03     4               13    0.30769231
#> 33             3     2009-03     5               13    0.38461538
#> 34             4     2009-03     4               13    0.30769231
#> 35             5     2009-03     1               13    0.07692308
#> 36             6     2009-03     2               13    0.15384615
#> 37             7     2009-03     2               13    0.15384615
#> 38             8     2009-03     3               13    0.23076923
#> 39             9     2009-03     2               13    0.15384615
#> 40            10     2009-03     1               13    0.07692308
#> 41            11     2009-03     3               13    0.23076923
#> 42            12     2009-03     2               13    0.15384615
#> 43            13     2009-03     1               13    0.07692308
#> 44            14     2009-03    NA               13            NA
#> 45            15     2009-03    NA               13            NA
#> 46             1     2009-04    39               39    1.00000000
#> 47             2     2009-04    13               39    0.33333333
#> 48             3     2009-04    10               39    0.25641026
#> 49             4     2009-04    13               39    0.33333333
#> 50             5     2009-04     6               39    0.15384615
#> 51             6     2009-04     7               39    0.17948718
#> 52             7     2009-04     4               39    0.10256410
#> 53             8     2009-04     6               39    0.15384615
#> 54             9     2009-04     2               39    0.05128205
#> 55            10     2009-04     4               39    0.10256410
#> 56            11     2009-04     3               39    0.07692308
#> 57            12     2009-04     2               39    0.05128205
#> 58            13     2009-04    NA               39            NA
#> 59            14     2009-04    NA               39            NA
#> 60            15     2009-04    NA               39            NA
#> 61             1     2009-05    50               50    1.00000000
#> 62             2     2009-05    13               50    0.26000000
#> 63             3     2009-05    12               50    0.24000000
#> 64             4     2009-05     5               50    0.10000000
#> 65             5     2009-05     4               50    0.08000000
#> 66             6     2009-05     6               50    0.12000000
#> 67             7     2009-05     3               50    0.06000000
#> 68             8     2009-05     5               50    0.10000000
#> 69             9     2009-05     5               50    0.10000000
#> 70            10     2009-05     4               50    0.08000000
#> 71            11     2009-05     3               50    0.06000000
#> 72            12     2009-05    NA               50            NA
#> 73            13     2009-05    NA               50            NA
#> 74            14     2009-05    NA               50            NA
#> 75            15     2009-05    NA               50            NA
#> 76             1     2009-06    32               32    1.00000000
#> 77             2     2009-06    15               32    0.46875000
#> 78             3     2009-06     9               32    0.28125000
#> 79             4     2009-06     6               32    0.18750000
#> 80             5     2009-06     7               32    0.21875000
#> 81             6     2009-06     5               32    0.15625000
#> 82             7     2009-06     3               32    0.09375000
#> 83             8     2009-06     3               32    0.09375000
#> 84             9     2009-06    10               32    0.31250000
#> 85            10     2009-06     3               32    0.09375000
#> 86            11     2009-06    NA               32            NA
#> 87            12     2009-06    NA               32            NA
#> 88            13     2009-06    NA               32            NA
#> 89            14     2009-06    NA               32            NA
#> 90            15     2009-06    NA               32            NA
#> 91             1     2009-07    50               50    1.00000000
#> 92             2     2009-07    23               50    0.46000000
#> 93             3     2009-07    13               50    0.26000000
#> 94             4     2009-07    10               50    0.20000000
#> 95             5     2009-07    11               50    0.22000000
#> 96             6     2009-07    10               50    0.20000000
#> 97             7     2009-07    11               50    0.22000000
#> 98             8     2009-07     7               50    0.14000000
#> 99             9     2009-07     7               50    0.14000000
#> 100           10     2009-07    NA               50            NA
```

Comment: Also, a quick search shows that this has been comprehensively answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596433/how-to-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-elements-of-a-vector-in-r/20596490

Comment: @Jarad No worries. I'm not sure what you mean by it being too many steps; the only step is really `t(t(cohort_table) / cohort_group[colnames(cohort_table), "InitialGroupSize"])`, the rest is just creating a reproducible example from the data you provided.