# How to multiply each column by each scalar in R?

Tags: r

I have the following variable `Q`

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
b = c(45,4,3,2)
c = c(34,23,12,45)
Q = cbind(a,b,c)
```

I also have another variable `r`

```
r = c(10,20,30)
```

I would like to multiply each column of `Q` by each respective value in `r` (for example, the first column of `Q` multiplied by first value in `r`, the second column of `Q` multiplied by second value in `r`and so on).

Specifically for this example, the output I am looking for is:

```
      10   900   1020
      20    80    690
      30    60    360
      40    40   1350
```

I am new to R and looking for the most optimal way to do this.

Comment: I think `Q * r` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Q %*% diag(r)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10  900 1020
[2,]   20   80  690
[3,]   30   60  360
[4,]   40   40 1350
```

or any of these:

```
t(t(Q) * r)

Q * r[col(Q)]

sweep(Q, 2, r, "*")

Q * rep(r, each = nrow(Q))

mapply("*", as.data.frame(Q), r)
```

See this answer for the same question except using division: 
[How to divide each row of a matrix by elements of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596433/how-to-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-elements-of-a-vector-in-r/20596490#20596490)

Answer (score 0):

you will just need to do double transpose:

```
t(r*t(Q))
      a   b    c
[1,] 10 900 1020
[2,] 20  80  690
[3,] 30  60  360
[4,] 40  40 1350
```