# How to divide each value in a matrix with the max value of the corresponding column

Tags: r, matrix

e.g.

`m <- matrix(c(1:9),3,3)`

the maximum values per column would be ...

`n <- matrix(c(3,6,9),1,3)`

how can I then perform an operation so that the output is a 3 by 3 matrix with the values: 0.33,0.66,1 in the first column (as the first column is divided by 3) 0.66,0.83,6 in the second column (as the second column is divided by 6) 0.77, 0.88, 9 in the third column (as the third column is divided by 9).

Comment: The last line of your desired matrix will be 1, 6, 9 ? Can you clarify the logic ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply`:

```r
apply(m, 2, function(x) x / max(x))

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.7777778
[2,] 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 3):

We can replicate 'n' by the `col` of 'm'

```
m/n[col(m)]
#         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.7777778
#[2,] 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
#[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sweep`:

```
sweep(m, 2, apply(m, 2, max), "/")
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.7777778
[2,] 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

or subset the max with `col`:

```
m / apply(m, 2, max)[col(m)]
```

or make a Matrix Multiplication with the `diag` of 1/max:

```
m %*% diag(1/apply(m, 2, max))
```

Have a look at: [How to divide each row of a matrix by elements of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20596433/10488504)

Answer (score 1):

With base R, you can use `pmax` like below

```
> t((u<-t(m))/do.call(pmax,data.frame(u)))
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.7777778
[2,] 0.6666667 0.8333333 0.8888889
[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: this would work well, however how do I adjust this code if there are NAs in my matrix?

Comment: @TheBeginner try `t((u<-t(m))/do.call(pmax,c(data.frame(u),na.rm = TRUE)))`