# How to do Multiplication of data frames

Tags: r

I have two databases, `df1` and `df2`. Therefore, I would like to multiply all the values of column `M1` of `df1` by the value corresponding to `M1` of `df2` dataset. Do this also for `M2`, `M3` and `M4`. How to do this?

```
df1<-structure(list(M1 = c(7464.65871998132, 7464.65871998132, 
7464.65871998132, 6828.03114705642, 6828.03114705642, 4283.33056756974, 
4283.33056756974, 4283.33056756974, 4283.33056756974, 4283.33056756974, 
2471.01407552018, 2471.01407552018, 1167.72213085951, 1759.83563490657, 
2832.42425394852, 2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 
2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 
2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 2216.93502047899, 1382.78244210074, 
1382.78244210074, 1382.78244210074, 1382.78244210074, 225.532020592308, 
225.532020592308, 451.757369238554, 451.757369238554, 451.757369238554, 
391.4333, 391.4333, 391.4333, 391.4333), M2 = c(0.717983998645269, 
0.717983998645269, 0.717983998645269, 0.728999753129052, 0.728999753129052, 
0.786965354287025, 0.786965354287025, 0.786965354287025, 0.786965354287025, 
0.786965354287025, 0.850074652422915, 0.850074652422915, 0.915840124863607, 
0.883139402208456, 0.835366766790403, 0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 
0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 
0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 0.861211447058532, 
0.903336851097558, 0.903336851097558, 0.903336851097558, 0.903336851097558, 
0.981191034215198, 0.981191034215198, 0.785270862340655, 0.785270862340655, 
0.785270862340655, 0.804079828125457, 0.804079828125457, 0.804079828125457, 
0.804079828125388), M3 = c(0.324701873490657, 0.324701873490657, 
0.324701873490657, 0.348051447072024, 0.348051447072024, 0.528241884225376, 
0.528241884225376, 0.528241884225376, 0.528241884225376, 0.528241884225376, 
0.713363517626057, 0.713363517626057, 0.861245569166058, 0.792956247672247, 
0.67415167385565, 0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 
0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 
0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 0.741455966636511, 0.836255759358446, 
0.836255759358446, 0.836255759358446, 0.836255759358446, 0.972845769144406, 
0.972845769144406, 0.668098499995622, 0.668098499995622, 0.668098499995622, 
0.675298126509343, 0.675298126509343, 0.675298126509343, 0.67529812650932
), M4 = c(0.984893346832548, 0.984893346832548, 0.984893346832548, 
0.898279272093836, 0.898279272093836, 0.552069187025303, 0.552069187025303, 
0.552069187025303, 0.552069187025303, 0.552069187025303, 0.305500984879433, 
0.305500984879433, 0.128186286770186, 0.208744159967084, 0.354671346857167, 
0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 
0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 
0.270933172866875, 0.270933172866875, 0.157445543929907, 0.157445543929907, 
0.157445543929907, 0.157445543929907, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.984893346832548, 
0.984893346832548, 0.984893346832548, 0.984893346832602)), row.names = c(NA, 
38L), class = "data.frame")

df2<-c(M1 = 0.269895498627542, M2 = 0.134785508607432, M3 = 0.147347188053672, 
M4 = 0.447971804711354)
```

Comment: `sweep(df1, 2, df2, \`*\`)`

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this here if you use `dev <- unlist(df2)` and `mat <- df1` and use * in place of / and use one of the solutions that start with `mat /` 
 here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596433/how-to-divide-each-row-of-a-matrix-by-elements-of-a-vector-in-r/20596490#20596490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible base R solution:

```
t(apply(df1, 1, \(x) x*df2))
```